# git clone doesn't find the remote repo

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I'm trying to clone a GitHub private repo. I've access to it

So what i do is (HTTPS)

```
git clone https://github.com/xxxx1/xxxx2.git
```

When i do that i receive:

```
Cloning into 'xxxx2'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/xxxx1/xxxx2.git/' not found
```

First thing that looks weird for me is the extra **"/"** at the end, but i don't think that's the problem.

The only way i can do the git clone is via GitHub Desktop App, by URL.

On **git status**

```
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.
```

On **git fetch**

```
$ git fetch
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/xxxx1/xxxx2.git/' not found
```

So the question is, **what i'm doing wrong to be unable to clone the repo trough git bash**?

Thanks so much

Comment: Do you by chance have multiple github accounts? Is there an authentication prompt when running `git clone ...`?

Comment: GitHub no longer permits https with password. Use ssh.

Comment: No does'nt ask me for username password @MaartenDev.

I'm gonna try as Matt said using ssh

Thanks so match both

Comment: Thanks mates. I didn't knew how to work with SSH Keys, but after learning works like a charm. Really appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's probably the case that you have an inappropriate cached credential for https in whatever credential helper you have installed and have told Git to use. The GitHub Desktop software doesn't use that credential helper, so doesn't have the problem. You could clear out the cached credential, after you figure out what's caching it, but I prefer ssh access anyway, it tends to be a lot more reliable. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SSH creation with Git bash: That worked for me**

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

**Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa):**

*Press enter*

```
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Type a passphrase]
Enter same passphrase again: [Type passphrase again]
```

*Press enter*

```
$ cd .ssh
$ ls
```

**Received**

```
id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
```

- First one is our private key (don’t share it to anyone)
- Second one is our public key

  $ cat id_rsa.pub

  ssh-rsa […]

On GitHub go to your user picture:

- Settings
- SSH and GPG Keys
- New SSH Key:
- Title: [Empty]
- Value: Our public key
- Click on: Add new SSH Key

On Git bash:

- cd ..
- cd Documents
- git clone git@github.com:xxxx1/xxxx2.git
- cd [name_of_repo_cloned_folder]
- git checkout develop

Answer (score 1):

If you are using two factor authorization (2FA) for your Github account then just use SSH option for cloning your repository:

[image]

Comment: I just followed a tutorial about working with SSH and everything went perfect. Really appreciated shrey.